# Perl capture stdout of embedded script, fails if in dlopen-loaded shared lib

Tags: c++, perl

I have some embedded Perl code in a C++ program (Ubuntu 14, Perl 5.18, if that matters) and I execute the Perl like in [this example](http://community.activestate.com/node/10859).

More specifically, I:

1. Create the perl instance, then load persistency code as described in the "perlembed" manual
2. Eval some "preparation" code:

   ```
   static const char * redirPre = "$scriptOutput = \"\";\n"
           "open(SCRIPTOUTPUT, '> :scalar', \\$scriptOutput) || print STDERR \"Failed to open scriptoutput: $!\";\n"
           "print SCRIPTOUTPUT \"huhu\\n\";\n"
           "select SCRIPTOUTPUT;\n"
           "print SCRIPTOUTPUT \"huhu2\\n\";\n"
           "print STDOUT \"huhu2a\\n\";\n";
   printf("PRE: '%s'\n", redirPre);
   eval_pv(redirPre, FALSE);
   ```
3. Eval my actual Perl snippet

Now the strange thing is that this works nicely if I statically link the code which calls all the Perl functions or if those functions are in a shared lib directly linked to the main program, while it does not work if those functions reside in a shared lib, which the main program loads using dlopen.

The Perl snippet executes normally, only getting stdout fails. Precisely, this part does not work:

```
open(SCRIPTOUTPUT, '> :scalar', \$scriptOutput) ||
  print STDERR "Failed to open scriptoutput: $!";
```

no matter whether I specify `>:scalar` or just `>`.

Interestingly, the output does not appear on stdout either, instead it says `Failed to open scriptoutput:` (but without any actual error).

Ideas?

EDIT: Re-routing stdout to /tmp/xx with the exact same code works nicely, the only difference is:

```
"open(SCRIPTOUTPUT, '>', \"/tmp/xx\") || print STDERR \"Failed: $!\";\n"
```

Comment: See above, actually there is a bit more which actually gets and prints scriptOutput ... Maybe the interesting question is, under which circumstances might that open(SCRIPTOUTPUT) fail???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent quite a while looking closer into this and finally found the problem:

Originally I loaded my own shared lib with `dlopen("mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY)`, that lib in turn was built with a reference to `libperl.so`. The dlopen man page states that the flags are propagated down when dependent libs are loaded implicitly, so loading libperl has just RTLD_LAZY too.

Re-routing stdout as described above involves the Perl lib `scalar.so`, which Perl loads at the time my Perl snippet executes. The lib `scalar.so` contains an unresolved reference to `PL_no_modify`, which again is defined in `libperl.so`. Now, since I did not specify `RTLD_GLOBAL` when calling `dlopen(mylib.so)` effectively `scalar.so` did not see `PL_no_modify` and failed to load.

After setting `RTLD_GLOBAL` in my code it worked.

The only remaining question is why Perl did not tell me ... :-|